# Syntax highlighting for sql files on sublime text

Tags: sql, syntax

I want to install syntax highlighting in my sublime text program for those extensions :

```
.plpgsql
.sql
.plsql
```

Somebody know how to do it ? I have installed some packages but there was no results.

Thanks

Comment: There's a package for Oracle syntax, including PL/SQL: https://github.com/bizoo/OracleSQL. I pulled it and made a few commits that have not yet been pushed back (as an option): https://github.com/wolfmoritz/Oracle. But the original works well.

Answer (score 4):

If you open a file of the type that you are looking for, and then pick

`View>Syntax>Open all with current extension as...>sql`

you should be good to go.

Comment: unfortunatly, this does not work.. Has `.sql` extension, but `View>Syntax>Open all with current extension` gives the same set of availible syntaxes as just `Syntex` menu...

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav That is how it should work. The answer was for telling SublimeText to use the generic `SQL` syntax for the other extensions as well. If you are looking for a different syntax highlighting scheme, you will need to find an extension that can handle it.